# How do you pass build result from one VSTS build task to another?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I have two build tasks in my VSTS extension (TaskA, TaskB), User will add the TaskA first and TaskB next in the build definition. I need to pass some information from TaskA to TaskB once taskA is complete. What should be the approach for this? Is this possible with vsts-node-api package? Please advice.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a variable by using console.log[("##vso[task.setvariable variable=testvar;]testvalue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md)"), then the following tasks are able to use this variable.

Comment: Thanks Starrain, Still I could not figure out a way to retrieve this and assign to a variable. Can you help me?

Comment: Found a way to retrieve via vsts-task-lib, Updated the answer.

Comment: @BandR You can retrieve the value by using var val = process.env["your variable name"];

Comment: What's the scope of a variable created using the above?  Is it in scope just for the currently running build?  Is there a chance it could affect another build running for the same build definition on the same (or another) agent?

Comment: The scope just for the current build and can't affect another build even through using the same build definition.